# How to run both doget(e) and dopost(e) in same app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I can run doget(e) in app script.But i want to run both doget(e) and dopost(e) in same script.I have coded two function and deployed as web app but i can only run doget(e),why not dopost(e).

```
 function **doGet(e)** 
    { 

      Logger.log("The value of mail id is" + e.parameter.umailid);

      var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'approved.All the best' : 'not approved.Try for the next event';
      var sub="OD Information";
      var Regno=e.parameter.regno;
      var Name=e.parameter.n;
      var CollegeName=e.parameter.cn;
      var EventParticipation=e.parameter.ep;
      var date=e.parameter.d;
      var message = "<p>" + "<b>Register No: </b> " + Regno + "</p>"
            + "<p>" + "<b>Name of the student: </b> " + Name + "</p>"
            + "<p>" + "<b> Attending at </b> " + CollegeName + "</p>"
            + "<p>" + "<b>Type of Event </b> " + EventParticipation +"</p>"
            + "<p>" + "<b> Date </b> " + date + "</p>"
            +"<p>" + Name +"'s   OD is  " + answer + "</p>";  
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
      app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to  ' +e.parameter.umailid+' saying: '+ answer + '</h2>'))
      return app
      }
```

function **doPost(e)** {

```
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('active'));
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
      var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; //read headers
      var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // get next row
      var cell = sheet.getRange('a3');
      var col = 0;
      for (i in headers){ // loop through the headers and if a parameter name matches the header name insert the value
        if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){
          val = new Date();
        } else {
          val = e.parameter[headers[i]]; 
        }
        cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
        col++;
      }                       
    }
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. We don't have the necessary information to answer it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: where is `doget(e)` and `dopost(e)` function?